# network-manager throws D-Bus failure: Variant type does not match match: Variant(Iter(UInt32))

Tags: rust, dbus, networkmanager

When I attempt to enumerate WiFi connections over dbus using the [network-manager crate](https://crates.io/crates/network-manager) in Rust, compiled and running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Raspbian Stretch 9.4 and network-manager v1.6.2, `NetworkManager::get_connections` throws `D-Bus failure: Variant type does not match match: Variant(Iter(UInt32))`.

`nmcli` works fine via the command line, so I suspect an incompatibility between the network-manager version and dbus, so I tried upgrading to the latest `dbus="0.5.4"` and `network-manager="0.11.2" crates by cloning the repos manually, but same error. Perhaps I need to downgrade some of these components?

Here is the entirety of my code:

```
extern crate network_manager;

use network_manager::{
    AccessPoint, AccessPointCredentials, Connection, ConnectionState, Connectivity, Device,
    DeviceType, NetworkManager, Security, ServiceState,
};

fn main() {
    let manager = NetworkManager::new();
    let connections = manager.get_connections().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: FWIW, that program runs OK on my machine, with NetworkManager v1.14.5-dev. I would actually consider upgrading NetworkManager on the target device.

Comment: I updated network-manager on RPi 3B+ to 1.14.4, which is the latest I could find on Raspbian backports, but getting the same error.